# xslt pattern match transformation

Tags: xslt

How can I transform the following XML with XSLT from this:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item label="21(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>
```

to this:

```
<root>
    <list label="21">
        <item label="(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>
```

So, if there is a number before a parenthesis on the `label` attribute of the first `item`, that number needs to be aded as the value of the `label` attribute for the parent `list` item.

The pattern to match the attribute would be something like:

```
/(\d+)\([^\)]+\)/
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and fully push-style XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Nikolaus you can use the `substring-before` and `substring-after` XPath functions. A sample XSL transformation would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <list>
      <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before(./item/@label, '(')" />
      <xsl:if test="$prefix != '' and number($prefix)">
        <xsl:attribute name="label">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(./item/@label, '(')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </list>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <item>
      <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="substring-before(@label, '(')" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$prefix != '' and number($prefix)">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('(', substring-after(@label, '('))"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: 0xA3 great code, but I do need it be happen only if the characters before the parenthesis match a number, this sample could match a string too.

Comment: You can check that using the XPath `number()` function. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the xslt function [substring-before](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-before.html) to get the substring befor '('

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="item[1][boolean(number(substring-before(@label,'(')))]">
    <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@label,'(')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="item[1]/@label[boolean(number(substring-before(.,'(')))]">
    <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',substring-after(.,'('))"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <list label="21">
        <item label="(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>
```

**Edit**: Compact predicate.

**Edit 2**: Test number **before** parentesis. Explicity strip white space only nodes.

Comment: @Alejandro: The transformation produces incorrect result on this XML document: `<root>
    <list>
        <item label="21(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="x(a)">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>`

Comment: @Alejandro: Another potential problem is that you don't explicitly strip whitespace-only nodes. If they aren't stripped automatically by the XSLT processor, then the `<xsl:attribute>` will be in error.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are rigth, thanks! What can I say? There are not general solutions... ;) Corrected to test number before parentesis, enforce first `item` pattern and explicitly strip white space.

Comment: @Alejandro: Now it's much better. +1.

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "list[number(substring-before(item[1]/@label, '('))
       =
       number(substring-before(item[1]/@label, '('))
       ]">
  <list label="{substring-before(item[1]/@label, '(')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </list>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "item[1]/@label[number(substring-before(., '('))
           =
           number(substring-before(., '('))
           ]">
   <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',substring-after(.,'('))"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <item label="21(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
    <list label="21">
        <item label="(1)">some text</item>
        <item label="(2)">some text</item>
    </list>
    <list>
        <item label="a">some text</item>
        <item label="b">some text</item>
    </list>
</root>
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. Beside that I like `number()=number()` test, I think that `boolean(number())` will make your answer more compact than mine.